# How to create custom HTMLElement using class extends in JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to create custom `HTMLElement` using class?

Whenever I'm creating unknown element, the constructor is unknown element (obviously).

```js
document.createElement("hello");
// return value: <hello></hello>
// constructor: HTMLUnknownElement
```

Can i create my own `HTMLElement` using class?

```js
class HTMLHelloElement extends HTMLElement {
  //...
}
```

```js
document.createElement("hello");
// return value: <hello></hello>
// constructor: HTMLHelloElement
```

Comment: I do not believe this is possible, as all HTML tags have to be contained in the HTML specification. Plus, how would the browser know how to handle this element? Certain tags (take `<strong>`) require special actions taken - the browser would have no clue what to do if it saw `<hello>` to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), specifically [Using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Comment: You need to define the element. `window.customElements.define('hello', HTMLHelloElement)`